# How to work with pixels in WP7 Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, image, windows-phone-7, pixel

I have an image, I want to get a pixel color, replace a pixel color with another, and other operations on pixels.

Is there a way to do that? And what libraries are needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) library. This will allow you to manipulate pixels directly.